# GMapsFX not displaying on Java 11

Tags: java, google-maps, java-11

I am trying to link my GMapsFX API with Java 11. I have just figured out how to use Java 11 with JavaFX and I am able to display and create javaFXML files, but I get an error when trying to use GMapsFX. I am using NetBeans.

Here is Main:

```
package javaformcoursework;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HomePage extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HomePage.fxml"));
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       
        stage.setOpacity(0.9);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    } 
}
```

Here is the HomePage.fxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="javaformcoursework.HomePageController">
   <children>
      <GoogleMapView prefHeight="525.0" prefWidth="700.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The controller class has no code so I am not showing it. Bearing in mind when I do not have the GoogleMapView on my FXML file, the code runs fine and a blank anchor pane is displayed.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView (in unnamed module @0x6ee2198d) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.sg.prism to unnamed module @0x6ee2198d
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.lambda$new$19(GoogleMapView.java:191)
    at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:228)
    at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:159)
    at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:137)
    at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:80)
    at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<init>(GoogleMapView.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at javaformcoursework.HomePage.start(HomePage.java:15)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application javaformcoursework.HomePage
C:\Users\Frankie\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Frankie\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: @MrUpsidown do you have a solution or you just came to edit?

Comment: Sorry no. I just removed the `google-maps-api-3` tag as this is not related to the Javascript API as far as I can tell.

Comment: right @MrUpsidown

Answer (score -1):

For IntelliJIDEA :
Go to Run/Debug Configurations and add this to[VM options:]
--module-path /YourPathToJavaFxLibs/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.web,javafx.fxml

Comment: I'm using netbeans